# How to change new Index number if value changes in Map

Tags: javascript

in Javascript

```
const qstndata = Object.entries(user.qstn).map(([key, values], index) => ({
      question_id: values._id,
      qs_no: index + 1,
      in_state: 0,
      section_index:    // here need to start with 1 if section_name changes
      section_name: values.sectionname,
    }));
```

if here `values.sectionname` changes  New Index number needed  how i can achieve this `section_index`

Comment: "if `values.sectionname` changes` How would this value change? Are you comparing it to the same property from the previous index?

Comment: values.sectionname comes from `user.qstn`

yes if compare with previous value if different need new index number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  let myindex = 0;
  let secname ="";
    const qstndata = Object.entries(user.qstn).map(([key, values], index) => ({
      
      qs_no: index + 1,
      sb_no :secname == values.sectionname?'': myindex =0 ,
      ss_no: myindex = myindex+1,
      secname :secname = values.sectionname ,
      
      section_name: values.sectionname,
    }));
```